# Node js Express js how to access json objects in POST method rawbody

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

How to request the data from rawbody as shown as JSON objects.

This is the my JSON values in rawbody [See this Picture if you can't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy9l2.png)

```
{
 "startdate" : "2017-05-28T09:00:00+05:30",
 "endddate" : "2017-05-28T09:30:00+05:30",
 "event" : "Meeting",
 "type" : 
   [
    "pickup" , "drop"
   ],
 "details" : 
   {
    "name" : "Zhunki",
    "address" : "madras",
    "from" : "vergeenia",
    "to" : "malpur"
   }
}
```

Now I want to get **event**, **drop** from type array, **name** and **address** from details objects.

My Express js Code is:

```
app.post('/trip' , function(req , res){
    var event = req.rawBody.event; 
    var type = req.rawBody.type; 
    var name = req.rawBody.name;
    var address = req.rawBody.address;

    var jsonresult = {
         status : 'ok',
         message : event + 'Created Successfully'
       };
    res.json([json]);

})
```

Please help me... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require `body-parser` and just use the parsed `req.body`.

Remember to `npm install body-parser`

```
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post('/trip' , function(req , res){
    var event = req.body.event; 
    var type = req.body.type; 
    var name = req.body.details.name;
    var address = req.body.details.address;

    var jsonresult = {
        status : 'ok',
        message : event + 'Created Successfully'
    };
    res.json([json]);

});
```

Comment: ok..but I can't get name and address its showing undefined undefined...Thanks

Comment: @RamAndroid because `name` and `address` are stored in a property called `details`...

Comment: Yes.. how to get that name and address from details.??

Comment: i have updated (var name = req.body.details.name;).. Now its working perfectly... Thankssss to @kennasoft and robertklep and Quentin

Answer (score 1):

The rawBody will be **raw**. It will be exactly what the browser sent. It won't have been parsed.

You need to parse it. You could use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) but you'd probably be better off with a [JSON body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions).